# How to use DOS font in WinForms application

Tags: .net, winforms, fonts

I want to use in my WinForms application a font used in .net console application.

What font do I need to use?

Lucida Console is not the font that is being used in .NET Console application as I see it. So Lucida Console is not the one I want.

Comment: AS arbiter asks, why isn't it the answer?  That is the font which is used in console applications.  Are there other requirements you aren't mentioning?

Comment: I found this thread http://bytes.com/sitemap/t-213834.html it says that there is no p-invoke-less way to use raster fonts on WinForm.

Answer (score 8):

Why Lucida Console is not the answer? Because it is. In english os, there is only two fonts for console: Lucida Console which is TTF, and Terminal which is bitmap (You cannot use this font directly, you must load vgaoem.fon if you want to use it).

You can read more [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2007/05/16/2659903.aspx). List of ttf fonts available for console located in registry: HKLM\Software\Microsoft\WindowsNT\CurrentVersion\Console\TrueTypeFont. You can read about requirement for such fonts in the [KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/247815).

And if you look into this registry key, you will see that by default there is only one ttf font available - Lucida Console.

Comment: I run my .NET Console App and I see that font being used is not Lucida. Lucida does not look cool enough.

Comment: So how would one load vgaoem.fon and use it? (+1 for your answer anyway)

Comment: Gdi+ does not support bitmap fonts, only ttf. So if you want use such fonts you need to via system interop (look at CreateFont win32 function).

Answer (score 0):

There is also Courier (New).

Answer (score 0):

It appears that your console/command prompt font may have been changed. Try doing this:

Open the command prompt.
Right click the icon in the top left of the window and select "Properties".
In the properties window, click the "Font" tab.
You'll see a list of potential fonts there, as well as the one that was selected.

I personally used a hack to get the Consolas font working on my command prompt, and the Courier New font is always a "classic" style font.

If you're referring to the window that pops up at the bottom of Visual Studio as your "console", you can find that font by selecting Tools->Options from the menu and selecting the "Environment Fonts and Colors" settings. Select "Output View" from the drop down list and it will display the font used.

Comment: Courier New is cool and all. But what I want is to simply have an app that looks like a console app with little extra effects. So I made a user control that uses a textbox with font set to (Lucida Console) for now, but it is different from "command prompt" window font (which is set to Raster Fonts 8x12, which is what I want).