# Replicate DOS console font (CP437) in Win32 app

Tags: c++, winforms, winapi, fonts

I am converting an old Console app to Win32, and want to replicate the font from the console.  The existing codebase forces me to work in C/C++.  I'm trying to use CreateFont and CreateFontIndirect to construct an equivalent.

The console font settings are:

[image]

I think I understand that raster fonts are not TTF and not directly supported, thanks to this post, [How to use DOS font in WinForms application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1069413/how-to-use-dos-font-in-winforms-application), and arbiter's answer.

I want to construct a fixed font that matches the 12 pixel height and 8 pixel width.

Here's some of the code I've tried so far.

```
HDC hdc = GetDC(w_child);
// "A 12-point font is 16 pixels tall." -- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff684173(v=vs.85).aspx
// "An n-point font is 4/3*n pixels tall"?
// I want 12 pixels tall, so 9-point, right?
int PointSize = 9;
int nHeight = -MulDiv(PointSize, GetDeviceCaps(hdc, LOGPIXELSY), 72);
ReleaseDC(w_child, hdc);

HFONT hf = CreateFont(
    -12,        //nHeight,          // Logical height
    0,      //nHeight * 2/3,    // Logical avg character width
    0,                          // Angle of escapement (0)
    0,                          // Baseline angle (0)
    FW_DONTCARE,                // Weight (0)
    FALSE,                      // Italic (0)
    FALSE,                      // Underline (0)
    FALSE,                      // Strikeout (0)
    ANSI_CHARSET,               // Character set identifier ??
    OUT_DEFAULT_PRECIS,         // Output precision
    CLIP_DEFAULT_PRECIS,        // Clip precision (0)
    DEFAULT_QUALITY,            // Output quality
    FIXED_PITCH,                // Pitch and family
    "Lucida Console"            // Pointer to typeface name string
    //"Terminal"
    //"Courier New"
);
*/

// Getting stock font, creating an indirect as a logical modification,
// seems to work better.  

// ANSI_FIXED_FONT, with lf.lfHeight = 10, results in something clear and
// readable, but a little too large. 
// And changing lfHeight seems to have no impact.
HFONT hf = (HFONT)GetStockObject(ANSI_FIXED_FONT);

// SYSTEM_FIXED_FONT at lfHeight = 10 is way too big
HFONT hf = (HFONT)GetStockObject(SYSTEM_FIXED_FONT);

// DEVICE_DEFAULT_FONT at lfHeight = 8 is way too big.  
HFONT hf = (HFONT)GetStockObject(DEVICE_DEFAULT_FONT);

LOGFONT lf;
GetObject(hf, sizeof(LOGFONT), &lf);
lf.lfHeight = 12;
HFONT nf = CreateFontIndirect(&lf);
SendMessage(w_child, WM_SETFONT, (WPARAM)nf, TRUE);
```

Comment: If you get the system font then the *w_child* window probably does not handle the WM_SETFONT message.  Which is not unusual, only the built-in Windows controls handle it.  Use SelectObject() in the window procedure's WM_PAINT message handler to select the font before you draw.

Comment: @HansPassant: I am using a built-in-- EDIT.  I would very much like NOT to have to roll my own control and write my own WM_PAINT.  But I am concerned that the EDIT control is somehow ignoring my WM_SETFONT

Comment: If you want somebody to debug your code for you then you'll have to post better repro code.

Comment: Hm, have you considered making a monospaced TTF that looks equivalent, and just using that instead?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans: I did but am not skilled at such.  I found the vgaoem.fon file, and may end up converting that.

Comment: I think the thing is the raster font is 8x12 and this 12 includes the height above and below each char as well as the char itself. These are stacked hard up against each other in the console window,so while each block is this large, the character itself isn't. That is to say, the CreateFont function uses a height (the -12 in your example) that _doesn't_ include the leading height, or height above each character. With a ttf font, the part below the line like for g,y,p etc is extra, so is the space between the top of a capital on one line and bottom of a g,y, p on the line above.

Comment: @enhzflep: thanks-- I was wondering why my admonitions to CreateFont to use 12 was resulting in typeface consistently too large.  Seems I'm really shooting for a 9- or 10- point ttf.  I will research.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like success in my situation:

```
 CreateFont(12, 8, 0, 0, 0, FALSE, 0, 0, OEM_CHARSET, OUT_RASTER_PRECIS, CLIP_DEFAULT_PRECIS, DEFAULT_QUALITY, FIXED_PITCH, L"System");
```

Comment: Rather than `12, 8`, use `-12, -8` to use "device units."